# jQuery .next(selector) doesn't give me anything back

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-selectors

I know that you can use .next() in jQuery to get the next element but I also know that you can give an argument, like a selector, and it will give you the next element that matches the given argument but in my case it doesn't work. Example:

HTML:

```
        <div id="divTEST"></div>
        <span id="spanTEST"></span>
        <a href="google.com">Google</a>
```

JS:

```
let div = $("div#divTEST");

console.log(div.next());
console.log(div.next("a"));
```

Now, the problem is not the div.next(), since I get the 'span' element back, the problem is div.next("a") because it doesn't give me anything in return. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: _"and it will give you the next element that matches the given argument"_ Incorrect. If you provide a selector, "it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector". In your example, the anchor is not the next element for the div, only the span is. Think of providing a selector to next as acting as a filter.  In your example, `div.next().next("a")` would work. More https://api.jquery.com/next/

Comment: That's what `.next()` is supposed to do. If you pass a selector, and the next sibling does not match, you get nothing. It does not search through the chain of sibling elements; it only looks at the immediately next sibling.

Answer (score 0):

This lacks the jquery reliance but if you use querySelector you can use css selectors to grab the element you want. querySelector just grabs the first one and querySelectorAll will grab any that match.

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('#divTEST ~ a'));
```

```html
<div id="divTEST"></div>
<span id="spanTEST"></span>
<a href="google.com">Google</a>
```

Comment: The explanation has already been taken care of in the comments on the question. I have no need to copy and paste those here. I am simply offering the op an alternative path.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use jQuery, I made a function to do what you want. It gets an element that matches the selector after the original element.

```js
let div = $("div#divTEST");

function getChildBySelector(elm, selector)
{
  const ch = elm.nextAll();
  
  let f = null;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < ch.length; i++)
  {
    const e = $(ch[i]);
    
    if (e.is(selector))
    {
      f = e;
      
      break;
    }
  }
  
  return f;
}

console.log(div.next());
console.log(div.next("a"));
console.log(getChildBySelector(div, 'a'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="divTEST"></div>
<span id="spanTEST"></span>
<a href="google.com">Google</a>
```

If you're fine with plain JS, you can use [@tstrand66's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67890533/15584743).